# Windows 7 - Unlock Computer remotely

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have recently got an EventGhost setup going, and I have a few actions, one of which is to remotely Lock my workstation. I was hoping to see if there was any way to unlock it, possibly using command line programs (or downloadable ones). Is there any way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are "numerous" ways to remotely unlock a workstation. However, most of the methods to remotely unlock a computer depend on hacks, dedicated background services, and such.

The safest way to unlock a computer is to just use a remote desktop program like the famous TeamViewer to enter the password directly on the remote computer.

Comment: I was hoping to have it be automated. Do you have any resources I could look at for the background services?